# Angular: direct use of service in view or through component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm writing an app, it has page1, page2, page3, all with components. I have one config.service.ts file setting the debug mode to a boolean.

In my views, I will (or not depending on this setting) show buttons/messages/etc.

What is the best practice ? Because both are possible:

1. declare `configService` as public in all my components, then in the view directly use:

   ```html
   *ngIf="configService.getIsDebugMode()"
   ```

   or
2. create a function in each component named `getIsDebugMode()` that asks the service for to know if we are in debug mode ?

```js
getIsDebugMode():boolean {
    return this.configService.getIsDebugMode();
}
```

and then in my views call the component function:

```html
*ngIf="getIsDebugMode()"
```

I think 2 is cleaner, but it makes me write three (or more if more pages) times the same function in all of my components... which seems like some kind of bad practice...

And I like to make it the right way, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug mode is not likely to change at *run-time*, and calling a *function* from a template expression disables expression purity. So Angular will have to call the function for each change detection cycle.

So use a *boolean* property for best performance.

```js
@Component({
   template: `<div *ngIf="debugMode">...</div>`
})
export class MyComponent {
   public debugMode: boolean = this.configService.getIsDebugMode();

   public constructor(configService: ConfigService) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your components extend the component that has that method:

```
class BaseComponent  {
  constructor(private configService) {}

  /*...*/

  getIsDebugMode():boolean {
    return this.configService.getIsDebugMode();
  }

}

class Page1Component extends  BaseComponent {

}

class Page2Component extends  BaseComponent {

}

class Page3Component extends  BaseComponent {

}
```